# Rails how to compare column value with sum of values in associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model project and payment

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I am trying to find projects which have total sum of its payments higher than is project target amount

```
@projects=Project.joins(:payments).where('enabled = true and amount < sum(payments.amount)')
```

this shows me error thay my attempt is too ambiguous

How should I compare field by sum from joined table?

Comment: another error: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I've found a solution how to use proposed mysql answer on postgres

```
Project.select("projects.*").joins(:payments).group("projects.id").where('enabled = true').having("sum(payments.amount) > projects.amount")
```

found it here
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1515

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your error is because of both table have same column name `amount` you can solve this error using `projects.amount` but `aggregate function` i.e `sum` is not allow in `where` clause of sql. you can use `group by` clause with `having` this way:

```
@projects=Project.joins(:payments).group("payments.project_id").where('enabled = true').having("sum(payments.amount) > projects.amount")
```

you can also try this way beacuse `PG` not support other column to select which are not in `group by` clause:

```
@projects=Project.includes(:payments).where("projects.id = payments.project_id and enabled = true").select{ |p| p.amount < p.payements.sum(&:amount) }
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "projects.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Hey which database you are using? this query perfectly worked in `mysql`

Comment: I use postgres for this

Comment: hey i think `PG` not allow to select column which are not in `group by` clause try my another approch

Comment: small progress but still not workin
`'irb(main):065:0> Project.includes(:payments).select{ |p| p.amount < p.payments.sum(&:amount) }
  Project Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
  Payment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."project_id" IN (43, 25, 24, 26, 27, 28, 32, 34, 36, 39, 42)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)`

Comment: hey where exactly an error? put complete error message instead of query and check you table and column names

Comment: this is the error, sorry it looked not readable
`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3)`
I checked table and column names, it is ok

Comment: hey for me it is work perfectly just try my updated post.

Comment: still not working 
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "payments"`
I tried to add references after where clause, but then I got error like before with wrong number of arguments